# What is the relationship between Windows Shell and the Shell API?

Tags: windows, architecture, windows-shell

The centerpiece of Microsoft Windows' UI is called [Windows Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell). Classically it was Windows Explorer, but I understand that in Windows 8 it's something else ("Immersive Shell"?) Anyways, it's possible to [replace the shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell#Shell_replacements) with something else - Windows itself supports Command Prompt as the shell out of the box, but there are [several 3rd party shells available as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows), and have been for more than two decades.

At the same time there's something called "[The Shell API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)". It includes a lot of functions, interfaces, registry keys, etc. which are designed to allow a program to interact with the Shell. You can, for instance, show the Windows File-copy dialog from your own program; navigate the [Shell Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), write an extension for the Shell; etc.

And this confuses me. If the Shell can be replaced, doesn't that mean that the Shell API is replaced with it? Won't installing a different shell break all the applications that use the Shell API? Even more - things like the Shell Namespace are essential to Windows as such; I can't imagine replacing it with something else.

Or is it so the Shell API is separate from the Shell itself, and every replaceable Shell must implement a specific set of interfaces (and adhere to mandatory conventions like the Shell Namespace) in order to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is separate.  The shell is Explorer.exe.  The shell api is implemented in DLLs.  So you can use them even if Explorer.exe isn't running.

Of course don't expect shell extensions to work in a replacement shell.

Comment: So does the Shell (aka explorer.exe or whatever else is installed) consume the Shell API or provide it?

Comment: Consume, Explorer.exe uses those DLLs as well.